# CodeBlocks step into gives unexpected error

Tags: stl, segmentation-fault, runtime-error, codeblocks

I have a strange problem with codeblocks, the thing is that when I run my program, it works, but if I try to step into the program and run it step by step, a `segmentation fault` error is given.

That **only** happens if I use STL containers. If I do **exactly the same thing** using arrays, there is no problem.

Did anyone have the same problem or does anyone know how should I solve this?

Edit: The segmentation fault is given right away, just after I Step into, not at some specific point.

Answer (score 0):

You've corrupted your memory causing undefined behaviour.

I'd use memory debugging tool like valgrind to locate the problem.

Comment: Well, the problem seems to be the latest version of the CodeBlocks. As I specified, my program WORKS if I run it. But if I want to watch the variables with step by step running, it colapsses as I described.
That happens in all cases of stepping into, stepping over or jumping to cursor, and I can not understand why

Comment: Those symptoms perfectly describe an example of UB. Correct program works in any environment, incorrect works in some.

Comment: But it is the same environment. It's in both cases it is the latest version of codeblocks. Only thing is that is I go step by step (step into/over or run to cursor) it gives the segmentation fault right away. If I just RUN it instead of going step by step, with the same program, works.
I just want to watch the change of variables, the program is correct and works